# Adding multiple functions in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
0-35    $52.00  
36-75   $55.00  
76-100  $63.00
101-150 $71.00
151-200 $79.00
```

In one cell I want to enter the weight and get out the price. These are the first two that work but I want them in one cell.

```
=IF(((D9>=0)*(D9<=35))=1,"$52")
=IF(((D9>=36)*(D9<=75))=1,"$55")
```

Comment: Put the data in a table with a column for the lower end and column for the upper end and a column for the value, then use VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott Craner replied, I also suggest you transform the form of intervals.

The interval range must be built in ascending order, an error value will be returned if the order is shuffled.

[image]

Then use Vlookup function to search.

[image]